# Parsing through SOAPMessage response getting null

Tags: java, web-services, soap, xml-parsing, unmarshalling

i am getting xml response from soap webservice but when i am unmarshall it i am getting null.when i am printing it on console it prints properly but when i unmarshall it Prints null.

Below is the code for unmarshall after getting response

```
private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse)
   {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
        System.out.print("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
       //StreamSource xml = new StreamSource(soapResponse.toString());
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(sourceContent);
        xsr.nextTag();
        while(!xsr.getLocalName().equals("HelpDesk_Query_ServiceResponse")) {
          xsr.nextTag();
        }

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(HelpDesk_Query_ServiceResponse.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    JAXBElement<HelpDesk_Query_ServiceResponse> jb = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, HelpDesk_Query_ServiceResponse.class);
    xsr.close();
    HelpDesk_Query_ServiceResponse response = jb.getValue();

    System.out.println(response.City);
    System.out.println(response.Organization);
}
```

Below is my java pojo class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class HelpDesk_Query_ServiceResponse {
    @XmlAttribute
    String Assigned_Group;
    @XmlAttribute 
    String Organization;
    @XmlAttribute 
    String City;
//other attribute and their Getter and setter
}
```

This line  **transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);** is printing the response in console like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns0:HelpDesk_Query_ServiceResponse xmlns:ns0="urn:XXXX_HPD_IncidentInterface_WS__XXXXX" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ns0:Assigned_Group>TIM-CSDWINDOWS-ADMIN</ns0:Assigned_Group>
        <ns0:Assigned_Group_Shift_Name/>
        <ns0:City>HYDERABAD</ns0:City>
        <ns0:Organization>XXX_TIM</ns0:Organization>
        <ns0:Priority>Medium</ns0:Priority>
        <ns0:Product_Model_Version/>
        <ns0:Product_Name/>
        <ns0:HPD_CI_ReconID/>
        <ns0:z1D_CI_FormName/>
    </ns0:HelpDesk_Query_ServiceResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

but when i unmarshall and trying to print city and organization value it prints null.
please some one help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems, namespaces and using attributes instead of elements :

Basically, you should use :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(namespace="urn:XXXX_HPD_IncidentInterface_WS__XXXXX")
public class HelpDesk_Query_ServiceResponse {
    @XmlElement(namespace="urn:XXXX_HPD_IncidentInterface_WS__XXXXX")
    String Assigned_Group;
    @XmlElement(namespace="urn:XXXX_HPD_IncidentInterface_WS__XXXXX") 
    String Organization;
    @XmlElement(namespace="urn:XXXX_HPD_IncidentInterface_WS__XXXXX")
    String City;
//other attribute and their Getter and setter
}
```